# Add subplots row header that scales properly in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I use annotate() (or any other command for that matter) to add a second "ylabel" to the right of a figure which makes the text "scale" the same way as the other texts (axis x,y-label and title)? With scaling I mean that I don't want to hack text offsets manually or have a solution which fails as soon as I rescale the figure/add more plots/add a colorbar or similar. I don't want to use twinx, because I'm not plotting any additional data, and I don't need another axis.

Here's an image of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here is my code to produce this image, I want to change the ax.annotate part:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numPlotsY = 3
numPlotsX = 3
f, ax_grid = plt.subplots(numPlotsY,numPlotsX,sharex=True,sharey=True)

A = np.arange(numPlotsY)+1.0  # Amplitude
phi = np.arange(numPlotsX)    # Phase shift
x = np.linspace(0,2.0,100)    # x

for y_i in range(0,numPlotsY):
    for x_i in range(0,numPlotsX):
        ax = ax_grid[y_i,x_i]

        y = A[y_i]*np.sin(x*np.pi + phi[x_i])

        ax.plot(x,y,lw=2.0)

        # Add xlabel to the left column
        if x_i == 0:
            ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$')
            ax.set_yticks([-4,-2,0,2,4])

        # Add ylabel below bottom row
        if y_i == numPlotsY-1:
            ax.set_xlabel(r'$x/\pi$')
            ax.set_xticks([0.5,1.0,1.5])

        # Add Phi label above top row
        if y_i == 0:
            ax.set_title(r'$\phi=%s$' % phi[x_i])

        # Add amplitude label to the right... how??
        if x_i == numPlotsX-1:
            ax.annotate(r'$A=%d$' % A[x_i], xy=(1.1,0.5), rotation=90,
                        ha='center',va='center',xycoords='axes fraction')

f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0,hspace=0)
plt.suptitle(r'$A\cdot\sin\left(2\pi x + \phi\right)$',fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

I've seen this topic discussed several times without an elegant solution. There's always so much hacking involved. I really think this boils down to the way matplotlib treats the axes. Why can't there be one label for each of the four sides of the figure, that behave the same way?

Comment: The easiest way for your purpose is second y-axis without this approach the only way to use annotate.

Comment: This is what I feared. Does anyone have an example of an easy way to use twinx/twiny without changing the layout and just adding the text (i.e. no re-scaling, no adding of additional ticks)?